# {"success":0,"message":"required field(s) is missing"}

Tags: php, android, json

When I test my PHP file in the web browser I get the message...`{"success":0,"message":"required field(s) is missing"}`. I am trying to add data from my android app to my database on local host and have no idea what the required field that is missing could be.

My full php is:

```
  <?php 

    $response = array();

    $con=mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
    mysql_select_db("independentretailers",$con); 

    if (isset($_POST['Retail Name']) && isset($_POST['Type of Business']) &&           isset($_POST['Location'])&& isset($_POST['GPS'])&& isset($_POST['Phone      Number'])&& isset($_POST['Email'])&& isset($_POST['Password'])) {


    $RetailName = $_POST['Retail Name']; 
    $TypeofBusiness = $_POST['Type of Business'];
    $Location = $_POST['Location'];
    $GPS = $_POST['GPS'];
    $PhoneNumber = $_POST['Phone Number'];
    $Email = $_POST['Email'];
    $Password = $_POST['Password'];

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO retailer(Retail Name, Type of Business,      Location, GPS, Phone Number, Email, Password)    VALUES('$RetailName','$TypeofBusiness','$Location','$GPS','$PhoneNumber','$Email    ','$Password')");

   // check if row inserted or not
    if ($result) {
        // successfully inserted into database
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Retailer successfully created.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
        // failed to insert row
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);
     }
     } else {
     // required field is missing
     $response["success"] = 0;
     $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

     // echoing JSON response
     echo json_encode($response);
     }
     ?>
```

My JSON Parse class is: 
    package com.example.independentretailers;

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

public class JSONParser {

   static InputStream is = null;
   static JSONObject jObj = null;
   static String json = "";

   // constructor
   public JSONParser() {

   }

  // function get json from url
  // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
  public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(nameValuePairs,    "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           


    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }
//      // try parse the string to a JSON object
//              try {
//                  jObj = new JSONObject(json);
//              } catch (JSONException e) {
//                  Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
//              }
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }
            // return JSON String
            return jObj;
}
}
```

The class I am calling my php file is:

```
  package com.example.independentretailers;
  import java.io.InputStream;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import java.util.List;

  import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
  import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
  import org.json.JSONException;
  import org.json.JSONObject;

  import com.example.independentretailers.R;
  import android.app.Activity; 
  import android.app.ProgressDialog;
  import android.os.AsyncTask;
  import android.os.Bundle; 
  import android.os.StrictMode;
  import android.util.Log;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.EditText;

  public class retailersignup extends Activity {
  private ProgressDialog pDialog;

  JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

  EditText etRetailName, etTypeofBusiness, etLocation, etGPS, etPhoneNumber,    etEmail, etPassword;
  Button bSave;

private static String url_create_reatiler = "http://10/0.2.2/tutorial2.php";

private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

 // @SuppressLint("NewApi")
 @Override
 public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    //setup strict mode policy 
    //StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new     StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
    //StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    setContentView(R.layout.retailersignup);

    //for Retail name
    etRetailName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    //for type of business 
    etTypeofBusiness = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    //for Location
    etLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    //for GPS
    etGPS = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4); 
    //for Phone Number
    etPhoneNumber = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    //for email
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    //for password
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText7);
    //setting up ID for the button 
    bSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    //setting up onclick listener 
    bSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){


        InputStream is = null;
        @Override 
        public void onClick(View arg0){
                 new CreateNewRetailer().execute();
        }
    });
}

class CreateNewRetailer extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{ 

protected String doInBackground(String...args){
            //storing values inside edit texts inside strings 
            String RetailName = etRetailName.getText().toString();
            String TypeofBusiness = etTypeofBusiness.getText().toString(); 
            String Location = etLocation.getText().toString();
            String GPS = etGPS.getText().toString();
            String PhoneNumber = etPhoneNumber.getText().toString(); 
            String Email = etEmail.getText().toString(); 
            String Password = etPassword.getText().toString(); 

            //setting name pair values 
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            //adding string values inside the name value pairs 
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Retail Name", RetailName));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Type of Business",       TypeofBusiness));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Location",    Location));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("GPS", GPS));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Phone Number", PhoneNumber));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Email", Email));
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Password",      Password));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest   (url_create_reatiler, "POST", nameValuePairs);
            //setting up the connection inside the try catch 
            // check log cat fro response

            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
            try{ 
                //setting up the default client
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            }
                catch(JSONException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

return null;
}

protected void onPostExcute(String file_url){
pDialog.dismiss();

}
}
}
```

I have been stuck with this issue for a few days now and any help at all would be really appreciated.

Comment: from you if condition , it indicates that one of your paramster is null or empty

Comment: do you know how I can find out which one?

Comment: if you could print this line params : `if (isset($_POST['Retail Name']) && isset($_POST['Type of Business']) &&           isset($_POST['Location'])&& isset($_POST['GPS'])&& isset($_POST['Phone      Number'])&& isset($_POST['Email'])&& isset($_POST['Password'])) {` it seems one of params is not correct and i can see lot of spaces here

Comment: i am very new to this sorry - does there be no spaces?

Answer (score 0):

When you test this in your browser, do you add any parameters to the path? If not, the output of that file is correct. If you do add parameters though and this is the output you get, you have to see if the parameters you add is consistent with what the script expect to get.

Also, you are making it harder for yourself using that spaces. See this part (and so on in your code):

`if (isset($_POST['Retail Name']) && isset($_POST['Type of Business']) ...`

To easier access (so you don't have to keep track on all those white spaces and tabs) you should use underscore:

```
if (isset($_POST['Retail_Name']) && isset($_POST['Type_of_Business']) ...
```

Though this is my personal preference (I'm not quite sure how it will work out with spaces). Anyway, you add parameters to your link like this:

yourfile.php?Retail name=Testname&Type of Business=Testbusiness ...